# Hibernate: data not being fetched when entity only has EmbeddedId

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a table in which the primary key is the composite key of all the columns (don't ask me why :(. I created an entity for it as below. When I try to fetch the data using Spring data JPA, it doesn't return anything. But from the logs, I can see that hibernate ran the query and it fetched data too. Please advise what am I doing wrong.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "PORTAL_CSV_HEADERS")
public class PortalCsvHeaders implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId
  @AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(
        name = "orderId",
        column = @Column(name = "ORDER_ID", nullable = false, precision = 9, scale = 0)),
    @AttributeOverride(
        name = "csvHeaderName",
        column = @Column(name = "CSV_HEADER_NAME", length = 100)),
    @AttributeOverride(
        name = "recipientMapId",
        column = @Column(name = "RECIPIENT_MAP_ID", precision = 22, scale = 0)),
    @AttributeOverride(
        name = "recipientDlfVal",
        column = @Column(name = "RECIPIENT_DLF_VAL", length = 100)),
    @AttributeOverride(
        name = "recipientDlfName",
        column = @Column(name = "RECIPIENT_DLF_NAME", length = 200))
  })
  private PortalCsvHeadersId id;

  @JsonIgnore
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private PortalOrder order;
```

Here is PortalCsvHeadersId

```
@Data
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PortalCsvHeadersId implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "ORDER_ID", nullable = false, precision = 9, scale = 0)
  private Long orderId;

  @Column(name = "CSV_HEADER_NAME", length = 100)
  private String csvHeaderName;

  @Column(name = "RECIPIENT_MAP_ID", precision = 22, scale = 0)
  private Long recipientMapId;

  @Column(name = "RECIPIENT_DLF_VAL", length = 100)
  private String recipientDlfVal;

  @Column(name = "RECIPIENT_DLF_NAME", length = 200)
  private String recipientDlfName;
}
```

Here is the association in PortalOrder

```
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "order", orphanRemoval = true)
  private Set<PortalCsvHeaders> portalCsvHeaders = new HashSet<PortalCsvHeaders>(0);
```

Comment: how does your repository look like?

Comment: Can you share the repository code and the SQL generated?

Comment: You store `portalCsvHeaders` in a set, so you should add `@EqualsAndHashCode` to your entity (and to the id too). I don't believe it will solve the problem it its own, but  it could worth a try...